# Android remove white border from cardview on API level 4

Tags: android

my android version is 4.2 and i'm trying to remove white border and space from that but my solution as `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"` from `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` namespace doesnt work correctly

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/market_item_background">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/market_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

this is part of my application which i used `CardView`

[image]

Comment: did you try following attribute together ? 

card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

Comment: @Amir this option as `cardUseCompatPadding` it cause of i get extra padding for cardview

Comment: cardUseCompatPadding is **if we set this property to true then margin works same on all versions** use -2 margin and guess your problem will be fixed.

Comment: @Amir No amir, your soluton doesnt work correctly on all of versions and thats not good practice

Answer (score 5):

Try setting

```
setCardElevation(0);
setMaxCardElevation(0);
```

and

```
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
```

Source: [Cardview - white border around card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392763/cardview-white-border-around-card)

Comment: yes, this solution only work when i dynamically trying to change that, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After much research only thing work for me with pre lollipop devices

with using both

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

in CardView,

this is a old question but might help somebody

Answer (score 1):

I set card background color to transparent and it makes the white border disappear

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `android:layout_margin="10dp"`

for `android:layout_padding="10dp"`

Answer (score 0):

I think that setting `setMaxCardElevation(0)` will be enough in that case.
No need in `setCardElevation(0)` or `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"`