# android cardview showing border around card

Tags: android, shadow, android-cardview, box-shadow, cardview

Android cardview is showing unnecessary border around the card. I have tried different things but I am not able to remove it.
It happens when I give the card a custom background color.
When I remove the cardBackgroundColor, and when default is used. Then unnecessary border is not visible.

I have to use shadow and tranparent color code.

Here is my layout CardView

```
         <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlUserNamePassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/form_card_bg_color"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/margin"
                app:contentPadding="@dimen/margin_large"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/user" />

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tilName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <com.yaashvi.placeandpeople.customviews.CustomEditText
                                android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="@string/username"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:maxLines="1"/>

                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_large"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/password" />

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tilPassword"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <com.yaashvi.placeandpeople.customviews.CustomEditText
                                android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="@string/password"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:inputType="textPassword"/>
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llGo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:elevation="@dimen/margin_large"
                >

                <include layout="@layout/go_button" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

And the view created is this

[image]

See the extra border on left, right and top of cardview and inside the card shadow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392763/cardview-white-border-around-card#comment64255333_30242617

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, it is a library, so will increase size of the app. Doesn't the cardview have any feature to remove this?

Comment: remove CardView app:contentPadding  and add the android:padding  in LinearLayout  of inside the CardView ...!

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/form_card_bg_color"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:contentPadding="@dimen/margin_large"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >
```

Answer (score 0):

i check it again and i got that result what you want.`<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimay >`

Answer (score 0):

try adding `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"` to XML code

Answer (score 0):

For me, it looks like that extra border is just the background of your RelativeLayout. I need to see the full code of the layout to confirm but if I'm right, this means somewhere maybe programmatically  your changing the transparent background of the RelativeLayout that you defined here

```html
please share the full layout code. thanks

         <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlUserNamePassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView...
```

Answer (score 0):

none of the following truly worked for me

what did work was making the inner image width and height 2dp bigger.
example:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="25dp"
android:layout_height="25dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="260dp"
app:cardElevation="0dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/image2"
  android:layout_width="27dp"
  android:layout_height="27dp"
  android:src="@drawable/test" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```